# How to change wordpress site domain?

Tags: wordpress, dns, bluehost

I created a site 5 days ago and it still has a temporary domain with the format "box###.temp.domains/~domainname".

I own a real domain and it is already registered on Bluehost.

When I change the temporary domain on WordPress settings to the new one, the site doesn't load.

I've already tried:

- Changing the site name on PHP admin.
- Editing config.php file.

Any clues on how to go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some config data in your particular case may be stored also in post meta table or theme config options in config table. Those are specific to theme / plugins setup and usually are not touched with native wordpress change domain feature. I suggest to make migration with plugin like: Wp Migrate DB.

Export your dev database with the plugin using replace strings 'old-domain/folder' to 'new-domain'.

Then import sql file to production database with sql client of your choice.